# i want to filter data with &,but got a wrong result

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, preprocessor

Here is my dataframe，i want to set the value satisfy `busSpeed<3` and `sationUuid==1` in the same time to be NAN ,but i got a wrong result ,anyone help, thanks

### below is my code

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
df=pd.read_excel('d:gps/9-20-32-36574.xlsx')
df.sationUuid.fillna(method='bfill',inplace=True)
df.dropna(subset=['sationUuid'],inplace=True)
df1=list()
for i in range(len(df)):
    if((df.sationUuid[i]==1)&(df.busSpeed[i]<3)):
        df1.append(df.replace(df.busSpeed[i],np.NAN))
```

### this is the data before processing

[image: original data]

### this is the result i got

---

[image: result]

`sationuuid` great than 1 was also set to nan,`if` statement seems only do `busSpeed<3`,how this happend

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with Pandas querying rather than with a loop and `if` block. Using Pandas querying has the added benefit of being much more efficient than using a loop. To replace the values satisfying your condition, you can use assignment with `.loc`.

Here's an example:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_excel('d:gps/9-20-32-36574.xlsx')
df.sationUuid.fillna(method='bfill',inplace=True)
df.dropna(subset=['stationUuid'],inplace=True)

mask = (df.stationUuid == 1) & (df.busSpeed < 3)
df.loc[mask, 'busSpeed'] = np.nan
```

So if `df` looks like the following after reading in from excel:

```
stationUuid  busSpeed
1            1.5
2            1
1            100
3            10
```

Then `df` will look like this after the rest of the script:

```
stationUuid  busSpeed
1            NaN
2            1
1            100
3            10
```

Comment: thanks woody,i know what you mean, but i want to set them to nan in the dataframe,instead of pulling it out.                                                                              i mean:when we do this out of the for loop,it works well ,but when i do this during it ,i got a wrong result.can you help for this.appreciate it

Comment: @zituoli I see, I made an edit, hopefully this is what you're after

Comment: it worked! appreciate to your patient explanation,thanks a lot

Comment: yeah,for sure,thanks a lot,Woddy,beside i have another question, can i ask your advise under this comment.

Comment: @zituoli yeah sure

Comment: thanks a lot,Woddy,you know my mean purpose is to clean the data  for forecasting(lstm),but when i do lot of denised methods,it seems the data can't be used,here is the original data:！[https://user.qzone.qq.com/1318757364/infocenter] and the denoisied data :![https://user.qzone.qq.com/1318757364/infocenter] can you tell me whether it can use or not ,if you do preprocess what would you dd.besides,sorry for the last two comments, i want to insert picture,failed.

Comment: @zituoli it seems I have to log in to see the data, but this also might be a more involved question than can be asked and answered in the comments. I'd recommend posting a new question with more detail on the problem. Let me know if you do decide to do that

Comment: Ok,i don't have the permission during the last two days,lol.i will tell you when i do it sooner.

Comment: Hi,Woddy，i have post the qusetion on:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52965939/can-this-time-series-data-be-preprossed-or-not-if-it-can-be-done-which-way-shoul,sorry for taking you so long.